# Lazy parsing of large files with millions of data points

Tags: parsing, haskell, conduit, attoparsec

I have a parser I'm trying to write and I've gone over multiple versions of it and I can't seem to keep the memory usage down. I'm trying to parse the wikipedia sql dumps and in this example take the page entries file and throw them all in one giant vector (13 million pages). I got this working before, but I sharded the file into smaller pieces and aggregated them from the filesystem. Anyway, below is my attempt to parse these files in one pass. I'm pulling out the lines `"INSERT INTO ... (data),(data)..(data);"`. I'm letting the other lines just fail in the parser and not yield values. The insert lines   average 1MB in size and 8k entries.

I've tried what feels like a thousand versions of this with deepseqs and outputting lists of page entries per line instead of the vector I have now and using lineC with a partial parser instead of the linesUnboundedC. I assume there must be some high level concept I'm missing that is keeping the memory usage exponential. The file is 5GB and I'm easily blowing through 16GB of memory, but I can't seem to nail down a lazy thunk memory leak anywhere. I would assume that this code would be able to store each line independently and then move on without the extra memory to the next line, but I can't figure out what is wrong. I had no issue counting the amount of entries or using a more complex monoid to get data from the file using the same parser.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Parser.Helper where

import Conduit

import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Monad (void)
import Control.Monad.Primitive

import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector.Generic (Vector)

import System.IO (openFile,IOMode(..))

data Page = Page !Int !Text !Bool
  deriving Show

instance NFData Page where
  rnf (Page pid title isRedirect) = pid `seq` title `seq` isRedirect `seq` ()

parseFile
  :: (Foldable t, Vector v e)
  => FilePath -> Parser (t e) -> IO [v e]
parseFile fp parser =
  do
    handle <- openFile fp ReadMode
    runConduit $ sourceHandle handle
      .| decodeUtf8LenientC
      .| peekForeverE linesUnboundedC
      .| vectors parser
      .| sinkList

vectors
  :: (Foldable t, Vector v e, MonadBase base m, Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad base)
  => Parser (t e) -> ConduitM Text (v e) m ()
vectors parser =
  do
    vectorBuilderC (1024*1024)
      (\f ->
         peekForeverE $ do
           ml <- await
           case ml of
             Nothing -> return ()
             Just l ->
               case parseOnly parser l of
                 Left _ -> return ()
                 Right v -> mapM_ f v
      )

parsePageLine :: Parser (V.Vector Page)
parsePageLine =
  do
    string "INSERT INTO" *> skipWhile (/= '(')
    V.fromList . catMaybes <$> sepBy' parsePageField (char ',') <* char ';'

parsePageField :: Parser (Maybe Page)
parsePageField =
  do
    void $ char '('
    pid <- parseInt <* char ','
    namespace <- parseInt <* char ','
    title <- parseTextField <* char ','
    _ <- skipField <* char ','
    _ <- skipField <* char ','
    redirect <- parseInt <* char ','
    void $ sepBy' skipField (char ',')
    void $ char ')'
    let ret = case namespace == 0 of
          True -> Just $ Page pid title (redirect == 1)
          False -> Nothing
    return $ force ret

parseTextField :: Parser Text
parseTextField = char '\'' *> scan False f <* char '\''
  where
    f :: Bool -> Char -> Maybe Bool
    f False '\'' = Nothing
    f False '\\' = Just True
    f _ _ = Just False

skipField :: Parser ()
skipField = void $ scan False f
  where
    f :: Bool-> Char -> Maybe Bool
    f False '\\' = Just True
    f False ',' = Nothing
    f False ')' = Nothing
    f _ _ = Just False

parseInt :: Parser Int
parseInt = signed $ decimal
```

Comment: What do you *do* with the data after you parsed it? Hold the entire thing in memory, or...? Have you profiled the code to see whether it's actually the parser that's holding on to the memory?

Comment: To amplify on what @MathematicalOrchid says, its possible that the caller of the parser is the one doing the retaining. If you sum a lazy list of N integers GHC will do in constant memory, but if you sum it and then divide by the length then GHC will retain the entire list so it can compute the length after its finished doing the sum. Maybe you are doing something similar.

Comment: I had a space leak with Conduit. Maybe something similar is going on. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786039/why-does-this-cause-a-memory-leak-in-the-haskell-conduit-library for details.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid For test purposes I just pull it into IO and print the length of the vector. What I actually need to do is to convert this into normalized maps and intmaps to do lookups on the next file. I've actually never profiled code in Haskell, I just found some resources in some comments on related questions suggested by stackoverflow.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Interesting, found this post http://www.well-typed.com/blog/2016/09/sharing-conduit/ on the bottom of the answers, still don't understand the problem well enough to know if it applies to me